# Inheritance - passing parameters to method VS using inherited proprieties

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance, parameters, abstract

I am really confused about this, i know that it's more reasonable to pass a parameter to a method, but when you use Inheritance all variables are exposed:

```
public abstract class HttpRequestBase
{
    public string Url { set; get; }
    public IWebProxy Proxy { set; get; }

    public abstract void SendHttpRequest();
}

public class HttpRequest : HttpRequestBase
{
    public override void SendHttpRequest()
    {

        HttpWebRequest objHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(base.Url);
        objHttpWebRequest.Proxy = base.Proxy;
        ....etc.
}

public class Class1: HttpRequest
{
       void Request()
       {
          SendHttpRequest();
       }
}
```

And in my WinForm:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Class1 obj = new Class1();
        obj.Url = "http://google.com";
        obj.Proxy = null;

        //Instead of passing the "obj" as a parameter, all these properties are already shared
        obj.Request();
    }
```

it make better sense to pass parameters but what is the purpose of the shared proprties if i am not going to use them ?

Answer (score 2):

Your `Class1` shouldn't possibly inherit `Request`; instead instantiate it when required. Its method should take the url as an argument - and internally delegate to a new Request instance.
Ofcourse 'Class1' is not a great name; you should use the appropriate domain lingo for the class name.

```
public class Class1
{
       void Request(string url, IWebProxy proxy)
       {
          var req = new HttpRequest();
          req.Url = url;
          req.Proxy = proxy;
          req.SendHttpRequest();
       }
}
```

Comment: I think incorporating an interface would have better decoupling, but this is the general idea.

Comment: There is already an abstract class, use that. Declare all the methods as abstract there. If you do not want to actually implement in a particular subclass just leave the method shell, and alternatively throw NotImplementedException. Otherwise the class heirachy shown implies a different interface declaration for each. Ugly.

Answer (score 0):

> it make better sense to pass parameters

In your example I think it does, but design intent clarifies the issue.

- Allow maximum flexibility. This sacrifices encapsulation to some degree and is potentially more error prone for the client code.
- Is the `Class1` object immutable? I.E. does changing the current `URL` or `Proxy` of an existing `HttpRequest` make sense vice an all new `HttpRequest`?
- *Guarantee* a valid object state

Make a `HttpRequestBase` constructor requiring 2 parameters - the `URL` and `Proxy`.

```
public HttpRequestBase (string url, IWebProxy proxy) {
    this.Proxy = null;
    this.URL = url;

    // how to handle null parameters? make defaults? throw exception? other?
}
```

**Why a constructor?**

If `URL` and `Proxy` are central/essential to a (derived) `HttpRequest` - if the notion of a `HttpRequest` existing without them does not make sense then constructor parameters enforces that idea.

If you don't want the client to arbitrarily change the object's `URL` and/or `Proxy` after instantiation.

Why put this constructor at the base of the inheritance chain? Same reasoning.

Why this instead of `Request()` method parameters? Same reasoning.

**Parameters make Flexible design**

As it is you "new-up" a proxy inside `HttpRequest`. This *tightly couples* `HttpRequest` to that proxy. I.E. every instance of `HttpRequest` must and will have the same proxy (state). What if that's not what the client code wants? What if you want to unit test (and you should) and you need to *inject* proxies and urls for testing? Instead let (force) the user to *inject* it via the constructor. Further, even if you intended this to be a default object (your public property `Proxy` leads me to this guess) *loose coupling* is more desirable.

**Encapsulation**

*Encapsulation* means that the client code does not need to know details of the class he's using. But in this case the client needs to know a whole lot about setting url and proxy. Does order matter? Why should he set proxy to null? Does he have to? Why does he have to? Does setting anything matter depending on what method he's calling? What must be set in order to call a particular method? blah, blah, blah.

> what is the purpose of the shared properties if i am not going to use them ?

If you have no purpose for them, don't use them. But again, this goes to design intent.

By "shared" I assume you mean `public`. In generic terms, to allow client code to customize the object (the object's state) at will. To the extent that you must not allow the client to shoot himself in the foot, don't.

Your intent here may be for the client to set these values immediately after instantiation; or to never change them once set, but programming is not rainbows and unicorns. You need to bullet-proof your design as much as practical.

As far as `private` or `protected` fields are concerned; to the extent that these are part of the essential being of a class then that's good. W/in that class they are simply there and passing these as "internal" method parameters is not as imperative as the public API.